# Using Google Analytics to get the unique id

Tags: c#, google-analytics

I have a site that I want to track unique users and wanted to see if I can use any of the  Google Analytics cookies. I see that GA is a unique tracker can I use that?

> will any of the below cookies are session that can be used an unique users?

[image: Cookies]

Comment: Is the cookie's domain the same as your website?

Comment: @gunr2171  Yes the domain is the same as the website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use cookie created by another site. A cookie only work from script running on a particular domain (google in your case).
You should use a tool call FingerPrinting to do what you want: https://fingerprintjs.com/open-source/

Comment: Would I be able to do it in an Handler using the Cookies.Add?

Comment: Why would you like to use-it that way??

Comment: I am recording traffic data using an Handler to insert data into database.

Comment: Check this out: I think that what you need: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Beacon_API